# Form attribute not being resolved by controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I've got hard time understanding how `[Form]` attribute works.

Consider simple razor form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.Hidden("id", 1)
  @Html.Hidden("g-recaptcha-response", "asdbasd")

  <input type="submit">
}
```

And a controller that handles the request:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Form("id")] string id, [Form("g-recaptcha-response")] string response)
{
  var explicitResponse = Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];
  return View();
}
```

Now the problem I have is that `response` parameter that is resolved with assistance of `Form` attribute is null while the one I named `explicitResponse` evaluates correctly to *asdbasd*.
To make sure this works at all, I've added *id* property which is resolved correctly using the same attribute.

I'll be diving into source code of that attribute to seek the answer, but perhaps someone has already done it.

So my question is: Why this attribute doesn't resolve the same value as I get explicitly from `Request.Form` and if there's a[image] workaround to avoid reimplementing that attribute.

Comment: I'd like to correct myself a bit. Once I changed parameter `string id` to `string someid` it resolves as null. 

As if `<param name="fieldName">The name of the form field.</param>` wouldn't be used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just me not paying attention.
`FormAttribute` is located in `System.Web.ModelBinding` namespace and it can be used by WebForms.
The correct attribute to use here is `BindAttribute` that is located in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

Modified code looks like this and works as expected.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")] string id, [Bind(Prefix = "g-recaptcha-response")] string response)
{
  var explicitResponse = Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];
  return View();
}
```